# How to create overlay video widget like has YouTube application?

Tags: android, android-layout, video, android-videoview

I'm creating application with video widget that has fullscreen feature.

My approach is, that I have got main FrameLayout and when I toggle fullscreen I add  black background and VideoView widget into this layout.

The problem with my approach is, that change of View structure where is VideoView stored causes MediaPlayer to restart playback, therefore video gets rebuffered - lag in playing.

#### Possible solution

Create overlay widget/layer, where is video played and resize this overlay to fullscreen or position it over area where should be video played. If I'm  not wrong. This won't cause invalidation of canvas, like it is when is videoview moved in view hierarchy. Therefore video should continue play like in new youtube application (android 4.3).

Unfortunately, I'm not Android master, just beginner with Android and this is my first more complex application. So, I can't implement this on my own and I also want to another overlay where is video controller placed and this overlay shall be placed over videoview overlay.